# Trying to customize a report name when I save it as a PDF in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

When I run the below code I get an error "Object Required". I want to be able to click a button and it will save this file along with a numerical field on the report known as `Market_ID`, then name of the report is Market Rate Notification Final. The report does show up but I do not get a save dialog box.  Also if I remove 
`Report![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID +` from `strReportName` I get a save dialog box with the file prenamed as Market Rate Notification Final.pdf.

```
Option Compare Database

'------------------------------------------------------------
' Export_MLR
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Export_MLR()
On Error GoTo Export_MLR_Err
    Dim strReportName As String

    strReportName = Report![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID + "Market Rate Notification Final"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen


Export_MLR_Exit:
    Exit Function

Export_MLR_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Export_MLR_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: replace "+" with "&" and try again. Also check if `Report![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID` gives and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to the contents of a report control like this:

```
strReportName = _
   Report![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID + "Market Rate Notification Final"
```

The result of the various errors is that strReportName is Null. First, it is `Reports`, not `Report`, next, you cannot get the value of a control in this way from a report, what you will get is the value of the last row of the report, and the concatenator is & not +, unless you are doing something quite fancy.

Comment: Remou, Thanks.  I didn't realize the "s" and I changed + to & then added DoCmd.OpenReport  All is good!   Function Export_MLR()
On Error GoTo Export_MLR_Err
    Dim strReportName As String
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Market Rate Notification Final", acViewPreview
    strReportName = Reports![Market Rate Notification Final].Market_ID & "Market Rate Notification Final"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, strReportName, "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen


Export_MLR_Exit:
    Exit Function

Export_MLR_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Export_MLR_Exit

End Function